# How to find the value of "WEBSITE_PHYSICAL_MEMORY_MB" for an Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've been looking all over and I can't find the answer. How do I find the value of "WEBSITE_PHYSICAL_MEMORY_MB" for an Azure Function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to find the value of "WEBSITE_PHYSICAL_MEMORY_MB" for an Azure Function?

You cannot find such a thing in Azure Portal as it is related to Backend Azure functions.

But, you can get it using below URL:

**https://resources.azure.com/**

- Click on Link
- Then click on Subscriptions,
- Then Click on your subscription
- Then click on resource groups, Then click on your resource group
- Then  click on `Microsoft.Web` and then on sites
- Then click on your function app name:

[image]

- Then click on `MemoryAnalysisFunctionApp`

[image]

Now you have got what you wanted:

[image]